# Passing data from php/mysql to flutter widget

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I had a problem with my flutter app here Getting data from mysql to  Flutter with php. Im not receiving any error but nothing show in the emulator but when im printing in function and result will print in console but inside the Widget build noting printing , and giving an error(value index is empty) it seems not passing value to widget build
here is my php code

```
    <?php
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $dbname="mobileapp";
    $password = "";

    try {
    //  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mobileapp", $username, $password);
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8;", $username, $password);

      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      //echo "Connected successfully";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
   $new_product = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product");
   $new_product->execute();
  // $new_product= $new_product->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $new_product= $new_product->fetchAll($fetch_style= PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 // header("content-type:application/json");
   echo json_encode($new_product);
    ?>
```

here is  product.dart

```
 class Product
{
  String title;
  String img_url;
  int price;

  Product({this.title,this.img_url,this.price});

}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mystore_app/Model/Product.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
class homePage extends StatelessWidget
{
  List<Product> myProduct=[];

  void getNewProduct() async
  {
       var url = "http://10.10.118.113:8666/PhpMobileProject";

       await http.get(url).then((response) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("This is list" + response.body.toString());

        List jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
          myProduct.add(new Product(title: jsonResponse[i]['title'],
              img_url: jsonResponse[i]['img'],
              price: int.parse(jsonResponse[i]['price'])));
          print("I is: " + i.toString() +
              "Title : " + jsonResponse[i]['title']+"Image "+jsonResponse[i]['img']+"Pric "+jsonResponse[i]['price'] );
          //  print("Image is: "+myProduct[i].img_url);


        }
      }
    });
    print("Product length is" + myProduct[0].price.toString());
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {

    print("Product length is" + myProduct[0].price.toString());
       getNewProduct();

   return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: listRow , itemCount: myProduct.length,scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal
      ),
      height: 300,
    );

  }

  Widget listRow(BuildContext context, int index)
  {

          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            width: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color:Colors.grey,width: 1),
                    color:  Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
              ),
             child: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 Image.asset(myProduct[index].img_url),
                 Text(myProduct[index].title),
                 Divider(color: Colors.grey,thickness: 1,),
                 Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 10),child: Text(myProduct[index].price.toString(),textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),), width: 250,)

               ],

             ),

          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `HomePage extends StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` and move your code into the State class, and insert `setState((){})` after your `myProduct` fetched.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
      myProduct.add(new Product(title: jsonResponse[i]['title'],
          img_url: jsonResponse[i]['img'],
          price: int.parse(jsonResponse[i]['price'])));
      print("I is: " + i.toString() +
          "Title : " + jsonResponse[i]['title']+"Image "+jsonResponse[i]['img']+"Pric "+jsonResponse[i]['price'] );
      //  print("Image is: "+myProduct[i].img_url);


    }

   setState((){});
```